# Google site search

Tags: javascript, html

I need to implement google site search I am using the below code

```
<script>
 (function() {
 var cx = '012847953619635190580:vrz-2wloub8';
 var gcse = document.createElement('script');
 gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
 gcse.async = true;
 gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
    '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
 var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
 })();
</script>
<gcse:searchbox></gcse:searchbox>
```

Problem is  shows a warning saying "unknown tag".

Pls help me out

Comment: Have you tried moving the script after the `</gcse:searchbox>`?

Comment: Script is in head and <gcse:searchbox></gcse:searchbox> is in body. Is that the right way?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the right way, as I've never used Google Site Search. You might want to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never had that issue before, but I use Google Site Search and can make some educated guesses.

1. Place that script tag at the end of the 'head' section of the enclosing file. It should be there ideally.
2. This is your best friend: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element

That page shows many different ways to implement Google Custom Search, and even gives you examples that you can toy with.

And on a side note, do you have a corresponding  section somewhere?

To quote that page: "two-column  and    A two-column layout with search results on one side and a search box on the other. If you plan to insert multiple elements in two-column mode in your webpage, you can use the gname attribute to pair a search box with a block of search results."

Basically, if you are using a 'searchbox' section, you will also need a 'searchresults' section.

Comment: Thanks Ben.. Will try and let u know.

Comment: Ben, we need to add our own div's for search box and result section in that we should place <gcse:searchbox></gcse:searchbox> and <gcse:searchresults></gcse:searchresults> respectively. Right?+

Comment: All that is required is this: 1. Have the 'script' portion at the end of your 'head' section. 2. Have <gcse:searchbox></gcse:searchbox> and <gcse:searchresults></gcse:searchresults> somewhere in your body. They don't have to be in seperate divs or anything if you are just setting up the basic version. What the script does, is find that tag in your html/php/whatever webpage file, and replaces it with its own code. Go ahead and look at the index file of http://searchcited.com/ , a site of mine, and examine the searchbox. That is where <gcse:searchbox></gcse:searchbox> used to be.

Comment: Mine is a bit different though; I set it up exactly like I wanted it.

Comment: It works Ben.. Thanks. But the search box is taking 100% width. How can I define my own style??

Comment: Simply put it in your own div, or span, or anything with it's own CSS or style. <div class="someClassName" <!-- OR --> style="width:500px;"><gcse:searchbox></gcse:searchbox></div>

Comment: Ya did the same :) Thanx :)

Comment: @BenYep Hi, What about situation you want to get results but with no Gui? (and I don't want to search the API, but the site).